# Wave Operators: Unitarity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This thread is Q&A.*

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider Hamiltonians:
$$H_\#:\mathcal{D}(H_\#)\to\mathcal{H}_\#:\quad H_\#=H_\#^*$$

Denote their evolutions:
$$U_\#(t)^*=U_\#(-t)=U_\#(t)^{-1}$$

For a bounded operator:
$$J:\mathcal{H}_0\to\mathcal{H}:\quad\|J\|<\infty$$

Assume the limit:
$$\Omega\varphi:=\lim_{t\to\infty}U(t)^*JU_0(t)\varphi\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{H})$$

Polar decomposition:
$$\Omega=J_\Omega|\Omega|:\quad\mathcal{N}J_\Omega=\left(\overline{\mathcal{R}|\Omega|}\right)^\perp$$

> Then one has:
>   $$\eta\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}):\quad J_\Omega\eta(H_0)\subseteq\eta(H)J_\Omega$$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote for shorthand:
$$\Omega':=\Omega^*\Omega\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad |\Omega|=\lim_n\Omega'_n$$

Regard spectral measures:
$$H=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda)\quad H_0=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E_0(\lambda)$$

By a previous thread:*
$$\Omega E_0(A)=E(A)\Omega\implies\Omega'E_0(A)=E_0(A)\Omega'\implies(\Omega')^n E_0=E_0(A)(\Omega')^n$$

So one arrives at:
$$E_0(A)|\Omega|=E_0(A)\lim_n\Omega'_n=\lim_nE_0(A)\Omega'_n=\lim_n\Omega'_nE_0(A)=|\Omega|E_0(A)$$

So one obtains:
$$J_\Omega E_0(A)|\Omega|=J_\Omega|\Omega|E_0(A)=\Omega E_0(A)=E_0(A)\Omega=E(A)J_\Omega|\Omega|$$

Regard an element:
$$\psi=\lim_n|\Omega|\varphi_n\in\overline{\mathcal{R}|\Omega|}$$

By continuity one has:
$$J_\Omega E_0(A)\psi=J_\Omega E_0(A)\lim_n|\Omega|\varphi_n=\lim_nJ_\Omega E_0(A)|\Omega|\varphi_n\\
=\lim_nE_0(A)J_\Omega|\Omega|\varphi_n=E(A)J_\Omega\lim_n|\Omega|\varphi_n=E(A)J_\Omega\psi$$

Regard an element:
$$\psi\in\left(\overline{\mathcal{R}|\Omega}|\right)^\perp=\mathcal{N}|\Omega|=\mathcal{N}\Omega=\mathcal{N}J_\Omega$$

By reducibility one has:**
$$J_\Omega E_0(A)\psi=J_\Omega1_{(\mathcal{N}\Omega)^\perp}E_0(A)\psi=J_\Omega E_0(A)1_{(\mathcal{N}\Omega)^\perp}\psi=0=E(A)J_\Omega\psi$$

By measurable calculus:***
$$J_\Omega E_0(A)=E(A)J_\Omega\quad(A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))\implies J_\Omega\eta(H_0)\subseteq\eta(H)J_\Omega\quad(\eta\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$$

Concluding the assertion.

**See the thread: [Calculus (WO)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1228041/79762)*

***See the thread: [Reducibility (WO)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1320238/79762)*

****See proof of: [Reducibility (SM)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1007385/79762)*